# Gmail Draft API returning 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to update a draft message with Google Apps Script. Here is the code.

```
 var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
 var params = {method:"put",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                muteHttpExceptions:true,
                payload:JSON.stringify({
                  "message": {
                    "id": draftId,
                    "raw": draftBody
                  }
                })
               };
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/"+draftId, params);
```

But it is returning following error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

I have verified multiple times that the draft id is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `draft ID` is different from the `message ID`. Looking at your code, seems like you're supplying `messageId` instead of `draftId`.

Try obtaining the immutable draft ID using [`Users.drafts: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list). This will return a response body with the following structure

```
"drafts":[
  {
  "id": draftId,
  "message": {
     "id": messageId,
     "raw": bytes
     }
  }
]
```

Then, you can use `draftId` when you update using [`Users.drafts: update`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update).

Answer (score 0):

You need the uploads URL.

developers.google.com - Users.drafts: update  |  Gmail API        |  Google Developers

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update